# Type error with recursion

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, types, type-mismatch

I want to pick every two elements form a list to make a new list, then I get an error like this:

```
test.hs:4:20: error:
? Couldn't match expected type ‘[a]’ with actual type ‘a’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      test :: forall a. [a] -> [[a]]
    at test.hs:1:7
? In the expression: x1
  In the expression: [x1]
  In a case alternative: [x1] -> [x1]
? Relevant bindings include
    x1 :: a (bound at test.hs:4:6)
    list :: [a] (bound at test.hs:2:6)
    test :: [a] -> [[a]] (bound at test.hs:2:1)
```

and here is my code:

```
test::[a]->[[a]]
test list = case list of
    []          ->[]
    [x1]        ->[x1]
    [x1,x2]     ->[x1,x2]
    x1:x2:xs    ->[[x1,x2],(test xs)]
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If the type of `[x1]` is `[a]`, then what is the type of `[x1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually preferred in Haskell to just write different clauses of a function – this does the same thing as `case`, but is often better readable. Also, please don't give your functions names like `test`!

Better like this:

```
chunksÀ2 :: [a] -> [[a]]
chunksÀ2 [] = []
chunksÀ2 [x1] = [x1]
chunksÀ2 [x1,x2] = [x1,x2]
chunksÀ2 (x1:x2:xs) = [[x1,x2], chunksÀ2 xs]
```

Now, each of these clauses must typecheck independently. I'll start with the second:

```
chunksÀ2 [x1] = [x1]
```

Hm. The signature says that the result should be a nested list and the input a simple list. So surely, you actually mean this:

```
chunksÀ2 [x1] = [[x1]]
```

That is a list whose only element is a list with one element.

Similar for the next clause:

```
chunksÀ2 [x1,x2] = [[x1,x2]]
```

Note that

```
chunksÀ2 [x1,x2] = [[x1],[x2]]
```

would also be possible. (Exercise: why is that not what you want?)

Where it gets interesting is in the recursive clause. You've correctly popped the first two elements from the input list with the pattern matching `x1:x2:xs`. Now you need to reassemble them. `[x1,x2]` is right at the first element of the result list, but then? `chunksÀ2 xs` has type `[[a]]`, so if you put it in another `[]` you'd have the type `[[[a]]]`. That's clearly too much wrapping!

Instead, you only want to *prepend* `[x1,x2]` to `chunksÀ2 xs`. Well, use the cons operator, the same you also used for the pattern match:

```
chunksÀ2 (x1:x2:xs) = [x1,x2] : chunksÀ2 xs
```

Finally, the empty clause. That actually works the way you've wrote it, but do you know why? Note that `[]` can have the type of any list you like:

```
Prelude> [] :: [Int]
[]
Prelude> [] :: [String]
[]
Prelude> [] :: [[(Double,[Maybe Bool])]]
[]
```

in

```
chunksÀ2 [] = []
```

you actually have

```
chunksÀ2 ([] :: [a]) = [] :: [[a]]
```

You could have also written

```
chunksÀ2 [] = [[]]
```

but that wouldn't do the right thing.

Comment: That really make sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`[]`, `[x1]`, `[x1, x2]` and `[[x1, x2], (test xs)]` all must have the same type to be possible values of the same function. I think you wanted `[[x1]]` in the second case and `[[x1, x2]]` in the third, because in those two cases there is exactly one chunk of length at most two. Note that you don't even need the third case because it is covered by the fourth for `xs` = `[]`. Also you can skip implementing this function by importing `Data.List.Split` and using its `chunksOf 2`.